# Order of eigenvectors sometimes important?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, diagonalization

For the matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & -1 \\
   -1 & 2 \\
  \end{array}\right)$$

I find $\lambda=1,3$ which gives me 
$\lambda_{1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array}\right)$ and $\lambda_{3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   -1 \\
  \end{array}\right)$

Now if I make the eigenvector matrix $$C = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   -1 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\right)$$

Then I can identify the rotation angles by setting the rotation matrix
 $$R = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
   \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
   \sin(\theta) &  \cos(\theta) \\
  \end{array}\right)$$

However if the eigenvectors are ordered the opposite way, it doesn't make sense with the rotation matrix. (Unless this means that we are interpreting it as a passive transformation instead of an active transformation?) Is this a case where order of eigenvectors does actually matter?

Comment: What do you mean by a passive or active transformation? Note that reordering the columns corresponds to composing the rotation with a reflection; this will not yield another rotation in general.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't make sense with the rotation matrix? Also, $3$ cannot be an eigenvalue of a rotation matrices